# Does const "this" pointer implies constness of all its members?

Tags: c++, overloading, overload-resolution

I know that if we add a "const" qualifier after a function declaration, it implies the implicit "this" pointer become const so we cannot **directly** modify any member

However, in a const member function, does every member automatically become const as well?

To illustrate what I'm trying to ask, here is a demo program

```
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
};

class Demo {

public:
    Demo() = default;

    void bar(std::vector<Foo>::iterator it) const {}

    void baz() const {
        // begin() is supposed to return iterator, not const_iterator
        bar(vector.begin());
    }

private:
    std::vector<Foo> vector;
};

int main(void)
{
    Demo d;
    d.baz();

    return 0;
}
```

Inside baz() method, I'm calling std::vector::begin() method, which according to [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin), can either return a `iterator` or `const_iterator`

```
iterator begin() noexcept;
const_iterator begin() const noexcept;
```

My understanding is that, if member "vector" is declared as const, e.g.

```
private:
  const std::vector<Foo> vector;
```

Then the overloaded form that returns a `const_iterator` shall be invoked. Otherwise, the overloaded form that returns a mutable `iterator` shall be invoked, which is the current case

When I try to compile it

```
g++ --std=c++17 -Wall
```

I got a compile error

```
main.cpp:17:13: error: no viable conversion from '__wrap_iter<std::__1::vector<Foo, std::__1::allocator<Foo> >::const_pointer>' to
      '__wrap_iter<std::__1::vector<Foo, std::__1::allocator<Foo> >::pointer>'
        bar(vector.begin());
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

which essentially `vector.begin()` returns a `const_iterator` rather than `iterator`.

Now I'm confused, I do not declare `vector` as const, why the overloaded form to return `const_iterator` is still invoked?

Is it because baz() is declared as const? I understand that in a const member function, all memory directly associated with current object shall not be modified, but I don't expect this to cause such impact on function overloading. I expect `vector.begin()` to return a const_iterator if and only if vector is declared as a const member, e.g.

```
private:
  const std::vector<Foo> vector;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The overload returning `const_iterator` is called because `vector` data member is `const` within a `const` member function. If an overload returning `iterator` were called, then `vector` could be modified through it. If data members could be modified in a `const` member function, then what would have been the point of marking it `const` in the first place? How would it be different from a non-const one?

Comment: `baz()` is a const method, i.e. `this` in it is `const` together with all its members. Therefore `vector.begin()` in `baz` returns a const iterator which cannot be passed to `bar` accepting a non-const one.

Comment: `this` is no different from any other pointer and `*this` is no different from any other lvalue. So your expectation is that members of a `const` object are not themselves `const`, right? Why would we need such a weak `const` modifier?

Answer (score 0):

Like everybody has said, if `this` is `const` then the members of whatever `this` points to are `const`.

To add on, you can have a member variable be non-`const` in a `const` function or context if you declare it with the `mutable` keyword... if you want that kind of behavior.

```cpp
class Demo {
public:
  Demo() = default;

  void bar(std::vector<Foo>::iterator it) const {}

  void baz() const
  {
    // begin() now returns iterator instead of const_iterator
    bar(vector.begin());
  }

private:
  mutable std::vector<Foo> vector; // vector is non-const in const functions
};
```